# XOR and XNOR equivalent?

Tags: xor

Why are XOR and XNOR known as "non-equivalent" and "equivalent" gates ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware, not programming. Try electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Wooble logical operations are often part of programming, so understanding them is often important. The simlest case is in complex `if`-clauses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XOR stands for "eXclusive OR", which means, that the result is true, when AND ONLY WHEN one of the operands is true, but not when both are true or both are false. This means, when only one operand is true and the other is false, they are different meaning non-equivalent.

**So XOR is only true, when one operand is true and the other is false.**

NXOR stands for "Not XOR", which in short means, it is true for each case when XOR is false and vice versa.

**So NXOR is only true, when either both operands are true or both operands are false, meaning when they are equivalent.**